# For loop in SQL to find 1's position in a sequence of 0's and 1's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function, sql-server-2017

Below is the for loop in c# which returns 1's position in a sequence of 0's and 1's here is my code

```
public string OnesPosition(string statusBits)
{
     string onePos = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < statusBits.Length; i++)
         {
           if (statusBits[i] == '1')
           {
              onePos = onePos + Convert.ToSingle(i + 1) + ",";
           }
         }
    onePos = string.IsNullOrEmpty(onePos ) ? "0," : onePos ;
    return onePos;
}

var result = OnesPosition("00000000000101");
```

This will return: result = 12,14

How I can do this in sql query or using SQL function?
Using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

Comment: There is no _For Loop_ in SQL Server. There is _WHILE_.

Comment: It's not really an SQL thing. Is there a reason to do this? There is an overview of `WHILE` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If you really need to do this in SQL, perhaps look into CRL Functions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sure, it's doable using some combination of variables and `CHARINDEX` function in a `WHILE` loop. But SQL is probably the worst language for this.

Comment: Yes I have another table which has description for each 1 position and based on position it selects color for that row(red, green, yellow, blue, white etc). It would help me easily sort by color rather I get these number in my application and use sort function in asp gridview using c#. :)

Comment: Convert your string into a temp table - location in string and related character - and then join the two tables where the character is 1.

Comment: Are you really just trying to do bit mask operations? Is your source data really a string or is it an integer that was converted to a binary string? If you have an integer then figuring out which bits are on is not too difficult.

Comment: How to find on bits if it's an integer?

Answer (score 4):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = '00000000000101'

Select Stuff((Select concat(',',N )
                From ( 
                      Select Top (len(@S)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                       From  master..spt_values 
                      ) s 
                Where substring(@S,N,1)='1'
                Order By N
                For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

**Returns**

```
12,14
```

Comment: I was just about to add a stuff answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Loops don't play well in SQL Server, but here is a method.

```
declare @ones varchar(16) = '00000000100101'
declare @pos int = 1
declare @result varchar(256) = ''

while @pos <= len(@ones)
begin
    set @result = @result + case when substring(@ones,@pos,1) = 1 then ',' + cast(@pos as varchar) else '' end
    set @pos = @pos + 1
end

select right(@result,len(@result) - 1)
```

Comment: For reference, this algorithm appears to be a modification of a [similar algorithm to find indexes of all string matches](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41961).
Also note that [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) was added in SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Elaskanator that post, and my answer, isn't an algorithm. I see that we both use `@pos` and a `while` loop... but that's about it. The post you referenced does create a resuable function for extracting the positions of a certain text using `patindex` which isn't needed here. This couldn't be a simpler use of `while`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Another possible approach is using recursive CTE (which returns each digit and digit positon) and group concatenation.

Using [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (from SQL Server 2017):

```
DECLARE @ones varchar(16)
SET @ones = '1000000001001011';

WITH Digits AS (
   SELECT 1 AS DigitPosition, SUBSTRING(@ones, 1, 1) AS Digit
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DigitPosition + 1, SUBSTRING(@ones, DigitPosition + 1, 1)
   FROM Digits
   WHERE DigitPosition < LEN(@ones)
) 
SELECT STRING_AGG(DigitPosition, ',')
FROM Digits
WHERE Digit = '1'
```

Using [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @ones varchar(16)
SET @ones = '1000000001001011';

WITH Digits AS (
   SELECT 1 AS DigitPosition, SUBSTRING(@ones, 1, 1) AS Digit
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DigitPosition + 1, SUBSTRING(@ones, DigitPosition + 1, 1)
   FROM Digits
   WHERE DigitPosition < LEN(@ones)
) 
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), DigitPosition) + ','
FROM Digits
WHERE Digit = '1'
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Output:

```
1,10,13,15,16
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use loop, but since you want it

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(45) = '000001000000101',
        @OutPut VARCHAR(45) = '',
        @I INT = 1;

WHILE @I <= LEN(@Str)
BEGIN
 IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, @I, 1)) = '1'
   SET @OutPut = @OutPut + (SELECT CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))) + ','; 
   --Convert.ToSingle(i + 1) why +1?
 SET @I = @I + 1;
END


SELECT @OutPut;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more method using a tally table and just straight tsql:

```
WITH Tally(i) AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS i
   FROM (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) a(n)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) b(n)
) 
SELECT bitloc
FROM
    (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(x.d, i, 1)  as bitset, i bitloc
        FROM (VALUES ('00000000000101')) x(d)
        CROSS JOIN Tally
    ) sub
WHERE bitset = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function based on @scsimon response and it worked.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertTo1Positions]  
(  
    @ones AS varchar(16),  
    @pos AS INT = 1,
    @result varchar(256) 
) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN  

   while @pos <= len(@ones)
begin
    set @result = @result + iif(substring(@ones,@pos,1) = 1,cast(@pos as char),'')
    set @pos = @pos + 1
end 
    RETURN @result;  

END
```

Answer (score 0):

or this...

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = '00000000000101';

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_Tally (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@string))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b
        )
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(t.n, ',')
FROM
    cte_Tally t
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING(@string, t.n, 1) = '1';
```